# How can I view the price of the item i selected from my list

Tags: .net, vb.net

Goof evening everyone! So tonight i am running into some troubles... I am supposed to do the following: 1)  Define a structure named Product. The structure should contain two member variables: a String variable to store the item number and a Double variable to store the price.
2)  Declare a class-level array that contains five Product structure variables.
3)  The form’s Load event procedure should read the item numbers and prices from the ItemInfo.txt file and store them in the class-level array. It also should add the item numbers to the list box. Code the procedure.
4)  When the user selects an item in the list box, the item’s price should appear in the lblPrice control. Code the appropriate procedure.
5)  Save the solution and then start and test the application. Close the Code Editor window and then close the solution.
So far, I have the following code:

```
Public Class frmMain
Dim newLineIndex As Integer
Dim index As Integer
Dim item As String
Dim counter As Integer
Structure product
    Public ItemPrice As Double
    Public ItemNumber As String

End Structure

Dim dollars() As Integer
Dim price As Integer

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
Dim products(4) As product

Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim file As String = "ItemInfo.txt"
    Dim product As String

    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(file) Then
        product = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(file)
        newLineIndex = product.IndexOf(ControlChars.NewLine)

        Do Until newLineIndex = -1
            item = product.Substring(index, newLineIndex - index)
            Me.lstNumbers.Items.Add(item)
            index = newLineIndex + 2
            newLineIndex = product.IndexOf(ControlChars.NewLine, index)

        Loop

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lstNumbers_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstNumbers.SelectedIndexChanged
End Sub
End Class
```

So now, my problem is, I do not know how i can make the price appear on the lblPrice when I select an item.
another question is, Is there a way to list only the item and not the price on the lstNumbers?
This is my interface:

[image]

and this is the file "ItemInfo.txt":

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @Magnas No. This is just an exercise i am trying to do to improve. It says intermediate but it seems like it is more difficult than some of the advance I did before.

Comment: Need to start with what the text file looks like. Is each product on a separate line?

Comment: Oops, hit enter too soon. What separates the item number form the price?

Comment: @Mary each product is on a separate line and below each product is the price. Below my original post is a picture of the file.

Comment: Anything that is text should be posted as text, not as a picture. If we want to test your code we have to type that file contents out ourselves instead of simply copying your data.

Comment: If your file data is one lines, wouldn't it make more sense to call `File.ReadAllLines`? You're not supposed to be displaying both the item number and the price in the `ListBox`. That's the point: the user selects only an item number from the list and the corresponding price is displayed. You're supposed to be creating instances of your structure and adding them to the `ListBox`, which you're not doing. When the user selects an item, it contains the price so you get it right form that item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you so much for the help and advise you gave me for this exercise.
The solution I used is below and it runs the way it is supposed to.
Here is part of my code:

```
Dim strItemNumber As String
  Dim dblPrice As Double
    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        ' return string variable
        Return Me.strItemNumber
    End Function
End Structure
' declare class-level array
Dim products(4) As Product
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' read all lines from the file
    Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines("ItemInfo.txt")
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    ' store price item numbers and price in the class-level array
    For x As Integer = 0 To lines.GetUpperBound(0) Step 2
        products(counter).strItemNumber = lines(x)
        products(counter).dblPrice = CDbl(lines(x + 1))
        ' add item numbers to ListBox
        lstNumbers.Items.Add(products(counter))
        counter += 1
     Next
```

Again, thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Explanations are in line
List(Of T) are much more convenient then arrays. No worrying about ReDim and keepint track of # of elements. Now, if this is homework and you must use an array see if you can change it yourself.

```
    Private lstProductList As New List(Of product)
    Structure product
            'changed the elements to Properties instead of fields becaus
            'the list box cannot bind DisplayMember and ValueMember to fields
            Public Property ItemNumber As String
            Public Property ItemPrice As Double
    End Structure

    Private Sub Project1Data_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim textfile As String
            OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() 'Drag a dialog to your form in the designer
            textfile = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            'instead of reading the entire file into a variable (which you named the same as
            'your structure - bad idea) read a line at a time
            Using sr As New StreamReader(textfile)
                Do While sr.Peek() >= 0
                    Dim p As New product 'an object of type - your structure
                    p.ItemNumber = sr.ReadLine() 'assign a line to the properties of your structure
                    p.ItemPrice = CDbl(sr.ReadLine())
                    lstProductList.Add(p) 'after the properties are set, add the object to a list
                Loop
            End Using
        lstProducts.DataSource = lstProductList 'A list of product
        lstProducts.DisplayMember = "ItemNumber" 'The property of product you want to display
        lstProducts.ValueMember = "ItemPrice" 'The property you want to retrieve when an item is selected.
        lstProducts.SelectedIndex = -1 'Nothing is selected at first
        lblPrice.Text = "0.00"
    End Sub
    Private Sub lstProducts_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lstProducts.SelectedIndexChanged
            'The $ indicates and interpolated string where you can insert variables directly in a string
            'The :N2 is the formating for the double converted to a string; N for number 
            'and 2 for the number of decimal places
            If lstProducts.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
                lblPrice.Text = $"{lstProducts.SelectedValue:N2}"
            End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: DId you intentionally leave out the setting of the datasource, valuemember and displaymember for the op to figure out or am I about to learn something I'm not aware of?

Comment: Oops! I somehow missed that very important code. Very sorry. Have edited my answer.